# Unable to fetch mapping in Kibana install on Windows 7

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, windows-7-x64, kibana

I followed the steps to install Logstash, Elastic Search and Kibana on Windows 7 machine and everything individually seems to be working fine. I can send logs to LogStash and they do get forwarded to Elastic Search. I loaded first two datasets as described in [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/getting-started.html). I can also view indices

```
yellow open accounts            5 1   1000 0  417kb  417kb 
yellow open logstash-2015.10.25 5 1    377 0 1005kb 1005kb 
yellow open .kibana             1 1      1 0  2.4kb  2.4kb 
yellow open logstash-2015.10.14 5 1      0 0   575b   575b 
yellow open shakespeare         5 1 111396 0 17.9mb 17.9mb
```

However Kibana is stuck at the very first step and no matter what index pattern I use, it always displays

```
Unable to fetch mapping. Do you have indices matching the pattern?
```

Developer console in Chrome and Firefox show same error message

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

http://mylocalhostname.com/elasticsearch/*/_mapping/field/*?ignore_unavailable=false&allow_no_indices=false&include_defaults=true&_=1445811221725

IndexPattern's configured pattern does not match any indices
```

I have tried deleting all indices and as is seen ".kibana" index was created after I refreshed the Kibana url. This indicates that Kibana can reach the Elastic Search. Everything is installed locally.

Versions:

```
kibana-4.1.2-windows
elasticsearch-1.7.3
logstash-1.5.4
```

Comment: use logstash-2015.10.* as index pattern

Comment: I have already tried all these combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same issue, I'm able to log the message to the Logstash, but not able to get that on to the Kibana UI. So after doing some research & had a chat with my friends, found that while indexing the logs from our application we need to format the date in ELK standards. I did this date formatting while indexing the messages to the Logstash.. Just add this to your index json array : **$message['timestamp'] = date(\DateTime::ISO8601);** this will fix the problem...

So here is the final data that I'm indexing :

> **$params = [
>                               'index' => 'my_index_name',
>                               'type' => 'log_messages',
>                               'body' => $message
>                           ];**

Happy coding :)